# Can a .ttl Turtle file have two empty prefixes?

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

It it possible to have a Turtle file with two empty prefixes?

Imagine that we have a `.ttl` file with this prefixes declaration:

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.com/example#> .
@prefix ex2: <http://www.ex2.com/ex2#> .
@prefix ex3: <http://www.ex3.com/ex3#> .
@prefix : <http://www.empty.com/empty#> .
...
```

Where do all the empty prefixes will be resolved: `http://www.example.com/example#` or `http://www.empty.com/empty#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#grammar-production-prefixID) defines it as a mapping `Map[prefix -> IRI]` so, no, you cannot have two for the same prefix (including the empty prefix).

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple definitions in a single file but **only one can be in scope at a time**.

For example:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/one#> .
:s :p :o .
@prefix : <http://example.com/two#> .
:s :p :o .
```

Would result in two triples because the file is parsed sequentially so the prefix mapping at the point at which a triple definition is encountered determines how it is resolved.

While this is perfectly valid input you will struggle to find a library that allows you to produce this as output.  And realistically it is probably best to avoid redefining prefixes during the course of a file because it reduces the human readability of the file and reduces the ability to cut and paste content within the file.

Comment: Necessary to give enough importance for the scope in turtle. Thanks.